# Past tense and present tense in one sentence

Tags: past-tense

> As he rides even in bad weather, sometimes he entered the building with his face and whole body covered with mud.

-> My intention: He regularly rides a bike, and he will probably ride a bike regardless of weather as well. And the times I saw him, he entered the building with mud on his face and body.

Is that a right sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of the sentence needs to be framed if there's no possibility of you seeing him enter the building in that way again.

e.g.

*As he rides even in bad weather, sometimes he entered the building with his face and whole body covered with mud **while I lived there**.*

If it's likely you'll see this again - if you still live/work/... there - then the main clause needs to be in present tense.

Comment: Yes, good point. My own answer assumed no further qualification. But if you place a further clause with a past time construction on it, then the past tense "entered" is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The implication of the sentence is that while he continues to ride a bike, he has (for one reason or another) stopped entering the building in a muddy condition, e.g. he now works somewhere else, or has taken to cleaning himself down before entering the building.  .

Comment: I think the intended sense is, "Used to driving even in bad weather, sometimes he entered the building with his face and whole body covered with mud."

Comment: @RamPillai But my point is that the use of the past tense indicates that the entering of the building has ceased.

Comment: Yes, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

To my ear it sounds a bit clunky. I'd suggest,

> As he rides even in bad weather, sometimes he would enter the building with his face and whole body covered with mud.

Comment: Again this implies that the entering of the building has ceased.